# How to send part of the output of a Python script to a text file?

Tags: python, save, text-files

I want to only save part of the output of script.py, and to a file in another folder.

script.py prints out a list of file names and their sizes, like

```
file_asfs.txt- 2KB
file_jsdfhkjh.doc- 17KB
....
```

If I want to save only the list of file names that are exactly 2KB in a text file /temp/filelist , how do I go about doing that?

Comment: In unix you can use `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc. to extract the parts you want from the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script.py | grep "\\b2KB$" > output.txt
```

Comment: I want to only save the file names, not the whole string including names and sizes...

Comment: I got it, using a combination of grep and awk

Answer (score 1):

you could create a program to filter it:
filter.py:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
        line=line.strip()
        if line.endswith("- 2KB"):
                print line
```

then go

```
python script.py | python filter.py > /temp/filelist.txt
```